# Unknown Selector Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to create a sign up page where people put such info as their email and desired password, after this is completed I want to switch to the next view controller however, I am getting the following error

> [StudyBuddy.SignUpViewController signUpButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fac5e061b80'

**SignUpViewController**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {



        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func signupButton(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    if self.emailField.text == "" || self.passwordField.text == "" {

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please enter a valid username and password", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        else if self.confirmPasswordField.text != self.passwordField.text {

            let passwordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Passwords do not match", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let passwordAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            self.presentViewController(passwordAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else {

            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!, completion: {(user, error) in

                if error == nil {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToSignUp", sender: sender)

                }
                else {
                    let createAlert = UIAlertController(title: "There was a problem", message: "There was a problem creating your account, please check the information you provided and try again", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let createAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                    self.presentViewController(createAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                })
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `signupButton` method declaration with `signUpButton` because inside your declaration `u` is lower latter for `up` you need to change it with `Up` because method name and property name are **case sensitive** or else change to selector with this `signupButton` one where you are adding target for button.

Comment: Correct the method names and properties are case sensitive.

Comment: Read my answer properly you get the answer or else change your method declaration with this `signUpButton`. Just capitalize the `U`

Comment: Change func signupButton to func signUpButton

Comment: Are you getting or not?

Comment: Yes thank you I got it, its been a long night so it took me a minute